# Pylinter in sublime text 2 throws error when saving python script

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I have installed sublime text 2 and SublimeLinter. Everything works just fine but when I try to save python file it always throws following error at me.

```
Writing file /home/asd/git/regex-gen/regular_expressions.py with encoding UTF-8
An exception occured when running pep8 checker: 'int' object has no attribute 'lineno'
error: Fatal pylint error:
pylint.utils.UnknownMessage: No such message id C0303
```

Please have you any idea why this is happening?

**Edit:** I have tried to switch pep8 check off, problem persists only error log changed a bit to:

```
Writing file /home/asd/git/regex-gen/supportive_functions.py with encoding UTF-8
error: Fatal pylint error:
pylint.utils.UnknownMessage: No such message id C0303
```

Comment: To narrow down what the cause is, you could turn off pep8 checking to see if that helps.  Look in the sublime linter settings and look for a line `"pep8": true,` and set to false.

Comment: Tried that, result is above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually it turned out, that problem was caused by **PyLinter** package, which I had installed in parallel with SublimeLinter. Removing PyLinter package solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
if type(loc) == int:
    loc = type('loc', (object,), {'lineno': loc})
```

to the `PythonLintError.__init__` method.

see: https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/issues/512

Answer (score 1):

For others' reference: I had the same error in Spyder, and the problem was related to my pylint.rc file (in my project directory). It had a list of pylint warning codes to disable, on a line that looked like this:

```
disable=C0111,C1001,R0902,C0303
```

One of the warning codes apparently didn't exist in the installed version of Pylint, which caused the "No such message id" error. Removing the offending warning code fixed the problem.